# При попытке сделать "img src" ссылкой все "сваливается в 1о место, в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: html, css

```css
.services.flex {
    width: 1300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.services.flex li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.services.flex a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font: bold "Montserrat", serif;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="services flex">
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="600px" height="300px" alt="">1</a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="600px" height="300px" alt="">2</a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="600px" height="300px" alt="">3</a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="600px" height="300px" alt="">4</a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" width="600px" height="300px" alt="">5</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в стилях. Вы как хотите, что бы это выглядело?

Comment: Ну и на кой у вас в стилях строчка `position: absolute;`? Вы в курсе что она делает?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, верстал по изначально под а href текст и уже потом решил сделать ссылкой картинку. Я только учусь, был не внимательным.